# Magento 2 : Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'

Tags: magento2.3, jquery, semantic-versioning

I am using below code to show modal, I am using semantic UI, I get below error

**

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'
    at Function.error (jquery.js:259)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (widget.js:186)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:376)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:142)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.<computed> [as modal] (widget.js:182)
    at <anonymous>:4:32
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Object.context.execCb (resolver.js:145)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1143)
```

**

My code

```
 require([
            'jquery','semantic/minjs'
            ], function($,semantic) {            
                $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
            }
        );
```

**I do not want to use magento 2 default modal , instead i want to use semantic-ui modal,
while debugging i tried to change jquery version in magento from jquery 1.x to jquery 3.x then above code worked fine but i am getting error on payment pages , is there any fix for it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I am using Semantic UI  Modal**
>
> *First you need to download and add to your module sementic css and js.* [click here to download](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/archive/master.zip)
>
> Get  **semantic.min.css** and **semantic.min.js** file and also get all **fonts** from this zip. And Add this files from below path.

```
app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/semantic.min.css

app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/css/semantic.min.js

app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/fonts/copy fonts add here
```

> *You need to change font path form semantic.min.css (fonts which you need)*

```
themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.woff
```

to

```
../fonts/icons.woff
```

> *Add CSS to your layout by adding this line*

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
            <css src="VendoreName_ModuleName::css/semantic.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- Call you Block and phtml  here-->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> *Now create* **requirejs-config.js**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'semantic': "VendoreName_ModuleName/js/semantic.min"
      },   
    shim: {
    'semantic': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

> *And call in your phtml like this*

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**sementic_modal_call.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
            'jquery','semantic'
            ], function($,semantic) {    

             $(document).ready(function(){
                 $('.ui.modal').modal('attach events','.test.button','show');  
              })        

            }
        );
</script>

<button id="mybtn" class="ui button test">CLick Here </button>

<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Modal Title
  </div>
  <div class="image content">
    <div class="image">
      An image can appear on left or an icon
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      A description can appear on the right
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui button">OK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 3):

By default, Magento 2 provides the Modal popup functionality.

Please check below code to open the modal popup

```
<div>
    <button id="click-here">Click Here</button>
</div>

<div id="popup-modal-main" style="display:none;">
    <h1> Content for Popup </h1>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($, modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Popup Title',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal-main'));
            $("#click-here").on('click',function(){ 
                $("#popup-modal-main").modal("openModal");
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: yes but instead i want to use semantic-ui modal how can i do that, with above code modal design is  not as per semantic-ui , update jquery version to jquery 3 solves my issue, but checkout pages gets stucked, any way to fix it